# getting currently set layout from an Android widget

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I'm developing a widgets app and the first hurdle I stumbled upon was letting the user choose from different layouts through a configuration activity and placing only one one widget in the widgets tab.

I solved this by creating different layouts for the widget and registering only one receiver and one provider. In the configuration activity, the user chooses from a carousel and I used a switch statement to set the proper layout, like this:

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());

            switch (carousel.getSelectedItemPosition()){
            case 1:
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getBaseContext().getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.first);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
                break;
            case 2:
                RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(getBaseContext().getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.second);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views2);
                break;
```

That was OK and I got the results I wanted, however, now I'm facing a new problem which is that I want to set an OnClick event for the widget witch will toggle between the current layout and another one, the problem here is that I can't get the layout the user chose for this specific instance of the widget as I have to define the layout I want to edit at the widget provider before doing any thing, like this:

```
    RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.second);
```

I searched for a solution and I thought I can use the getLayoutId() method for getting the layout, however, it isn't possible unless you specify the layout yourself.

I'm currently stuck at this point, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks